# Abstract PHP Class for performing lookups to MySQL and XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, abstract-class

I am currently building a library that will be used as the primary storage engine for a website. It is just going to pull information from a MySQL database, but I want to create variants (that use the same functions and arguments) to get and set data from other storage systems, like XML or MSSQL, so there would be no re-programming required if the database type was changed. An added bonus is to also add security into it to help prevent SQL-Injection attacks.

The issue i'm having at the moment is the abstract of the class. I am not sure on how to structure it in a way that will work for different types (so I can't just have a SQL string). Does anyone have any ideas on what arguments could be provided. I was thinking of using nested arrays to create brackets and define operators for the Query, but that could be used for direct analysis when using XML.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question (in which case, I'll edit or delete the answer), but if I'm getting you correctly:

It depends on your use cases, but if possible, I would just use the same interface as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) .  Then you can just use PDO drivers for the things where they exist.  And other programmers will have an easy time understanding your API.

Comment: sort of, but i was trying to use something where it would all be in the same argument to keep it tightly knitted. i've already decided that the return will be an array of the data rows (each row as a nested array, and in that array, the key will be the column and the value is the value). But PDO does look useful, but it doesn't contain XML. The reason is because i have written websites for people who are adamant about hosting it themselves, but are too cheap to upgrade their hosting package. was going to use this as a quick workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What about using two OOP inheriting branches: for queries and for data?

```
class query {
    protected $row_classname = 'row';

    protected $params = array();

    protected $result;

    public function bind_param($name, $value) { ... }

    public function execute() {
        //here go some common cache issues, param checks, etc.
        $this->run_query();
    }

    public function get_result() {
        //you can map it to $this using __get and __set
        return $this->result;
    }

    abstract function run_query();
}

class sql_query extends query {
    protected $pdo_connection;

    protected $pdo_statement;

    protected function run_query() {
        $this->pdo_statement = $this->get_pdo()->prepare($this->get_statement());
        $this->pdo_statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->row_classname);
        $this->bind_params_to_pdo_statement();
        $this->pdo_statement->execute();
        $this->result = $this->pdo_statement->fetchAll();
    }
}

class select_users_by_id extends sql_query {
    protected $row_classname = 'user_row';

    protected function get_statement() {
        return 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id';
    }
}


//memcached branch
class memcached_query extends query {
    protected function run_query() {
        $this->result = new $this->row_classname;
        $results = $this->action();

        foreach($results AS $k => $v) {
            $this->result->$k = $v;
        }
    }

    abstract protected function action();
}

class get_user_by_id extends memcached_query {
    protected $row_classname = 'user_row';

    protected function action() {
        $this->get_memcached_handler()->get_by_key($this->params['key']);
    }
}

//usage in project
...
$users_by_id = new select_users_by_id();
$users_by_id->bind('id', 14);
$users_by_id->execute();

var_dump($users_by_id->get_result()->name);

...

//user_row branch
class row {
    protected $row = array();

        public function __set($name, $value) {
            $this->row[$name] = $value;
        }

        public function __get($name) {
            return $this->row[$name];
        }
}

class user_row extends row {
    ...
}
```